# How can I post a comment in .NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

Let's say I have a blog post with the appropriate view model (contents of the post, who wrote it, etc).  Everything in the page is bound to this view model.  Then, down the bottom, I have a comments section, where the comments are rendered in using a @foreach loop.

If someone wants to post a new comment, how can I make my  tag post to the correct action to add their new comment in?  I have considered adding a "NewComment" field to the view model, and checking that on post to see if it has anything in it and taking action accordingly, but it feels yucky.  If I could define a new @model for the  tag, I feel like would work, but as far as I know I can't do that.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can include a partial view in the view that is based on a `Comment` (where the partial has `@model Comment`)

Answer (score 1):

You could try `ViewComponent` and detail steps are below:

1. Define Post class and Comment class are one-to-many relationships

   ```
    public class Post
   {
       public int PostId { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Content { get; set; }
       public Blog Blog { get; set; }
       public List<Comment> Comments{get;set;}
   }
    public class Comment
   {
       public int CommentId { get; set; }
       public string CContent { get; set; }
       public Post Post { get; set; }
       public int PostId { get; set; }
       public Blog Blog { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. In Post Details.cshtml , use ViewComponent to realize the comment list

   ```
   @model Comment
   @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
    }
   <h2>Details</h2>

   <div>
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("Post", new { PostId = @Model.PostId })
   </div>
    @* Add Comment *@
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <form asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Posts">
           <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
           <input asp-for="PostId" class="form-control" />
           <div class="form-group">
               <label asp-for="CContent" class="control-label"></label>
               <input asp-for="CContent" class="form-control" />
               <span asp-validation-for="CContent" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
   ```
3. The code of  PostViewComponent page

   ```
     @model Post
     <h4> Comment List</h4>
      <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <form asp-action="CreateComment" asp-controller="Posts">
           <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <label asp-for="PostId" class="control-label"></label>
               <input asp-for="PostId" class="form-control" />
               <span asp-validation-for="PostId" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
               <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
               <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
      </div>
         @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
        {
   <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="@comment.CommentId" class="control-label"></label>
       <input asp-for="@comment.CommentId" class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="@comment.CContent" class="control-label"></label>
       <input asp-for="@comment.CContent" class="form-control" />
   </div>
     }
   ```
4. The code of  PostViewComponent class

   ```
     public class PostViewComponent : ViewComponent
   {
       private readonly PostCommentContext _context;
       public PostViewComponent(PostCommentContext context)
       {
           _context = context;
       }
       public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int PostId)
       {
           var items = await _context.Posts.Include(p => p.Comments)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PostId == PostId);
           return View(items);
           //return View(new Comment() { PostId = Id });
       }
   }
   ```
5. The action of getting comment list  and adding  comments in PostsController

   ```
       [HttpGet("Posts/Details/{PostId}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? PostId)
   {

       var comment = new Comment { PostId = PostId.Value};
       return View(comment);
   }
   [HttpPost("Posts/Details/{PostId}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> CreateComment(int PostId, Comment comment)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           _context.Add(comment);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

           return View("Details", new Comment { PostId = comment.PostId });
       }
       return View("Posts/Details");
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I would say ViewComponents are the way to go. You can send any data to them when calling their Invoke method and they use their own models.